# How can I modify LaTeX commands to center company/university names and make position independent of column length in resume headings?

Tags: pdftex, horizontal-alignment, formatting, overleaf, resume

I have these two commands for resume headings, but it doesn't give me the desired look that I want

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\input{glyphtounicode}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.7in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable
\pdfgentounicode=1

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}




\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}
    {0.97\textwidth}[t]{p{5.8cm}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l@{}r@{\extracolsep{4mm}}r}
      \textit{\large #3} & \textbf{\underline{#1}} & \textit{\small#2} &  \textit{\small #4}
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheadingEdu}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}
    {0.97\textwidth}[t]{p{5.8cm}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l@{}r@{\extracolsep{4mm}}r}
      \textit{\large #3} & \textbf{\large\underline{#1}} & \textit{\small#2} &  \textit{\small #4}
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}
}


\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\footskip}{4.08003pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

  {\href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe/}{\huge {\textsc{John Doe}}}}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \textbullet \ Toronto, ON
    \textbullet \ \href{mailto:john.doe@gmail.com}{john.doe@gmail.com} 
    \textbullet \ 333-222-4444 
{LinkedIn}   
\end{center}
\vspace{-10pt}

\section{\textbf{Professional experience}}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Company 1}{United States}
      {Senior Software Developer}{12/2022 - 12/2023}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \item {item 1},
      \resumeItemListEnd

    

    \resumeSubheading
      {Company4}{Germany}
      { Full Stack Developer}{07/2020 - 07/2021}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \item item1
      \resumeItemListEnd
      
  

    \resumeSubheading{Company6}{Netherlands}{Front-end Developer (part-time)}{Sep 2015 - Sep 2017}
    \resumeItemListStart
        \item {item1}
    \resumeItemListEnd
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

\section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheadingEdu{University of Florida}{USA, FL}{M.Sc. Computer Engineering}{}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

\end{document}
```

Here's a sample output, but I want the company name (or university name) to be centered, and their position to be independent of the first column's length, the text in the first column wouldn't be super long, no longer than "Senior Software Developer", how can I modify these commands to get my desired output?
Or even better how to have only one command to achieve a similar result?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Instead of a bunch of tabular*s, one tabular or tabularx should do.  that way all the columns will be aligned.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: would you like to upload your code as a minimum working example to work with

Answer (score 2):

You can use the commands `\rlap`, `\clap`, and `\llap` to collapse the items left, center, and right to zero width and then use `\hfill` to center. If any of the parts gets too long, it will overlap with the neighboring ones.

Be careful with spaces in command definitions and command arguments, as they may show in the typeset text.

```
\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{%
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
  \mbox{}%
  \rlap{\itshape\large#3}%
  \hfill
  \clap{\bfseries\underline{#1}}%
  \hfill
  \llap{\itshape\small#2 #4\unskip}%
  \vspace{-5pt}%
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheadingEdu}[4]{%
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
  \mbox{}%
  \rlap{\itshape\large#3}%
  \hfill
  \clap{\large\underline{#1}}%
  \hfill
  \llap{\itshape\small#2 #4\unskip}%
  \vspace{-6pt}%
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\input{glyphtounicode}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.7in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable
\pdfgentounicode=1

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}




\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{%
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
  \mbox{}%
  \rlap{\itshape\large#3}%
  \hfill
  \clap{\bfseries\underline{#1}}%
  \hfill
  \llap{\itshape\small#2 #4\unskip}%
  \vspace{-5pt}%
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheadingEdu}[4]{%
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
  \mbox{}%
  \rlap{\itshape\large#3}%
  \hfill
  \clap{\large\underline{#1}}%
  \hfill
  \llap{\itshape\small#2 #4\unskip}%
  \vspace{-6pt}%
}


\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\footskip}{4.08003pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

  {\href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe/}{\huge {\textsc{John Doe}}}}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \textbullet \ Toronto, ON
    \textbullet \ \href{mailto:john.doe@gmail.com}{john.doe@gmail.com} 
    \textbullet \ 333-222-4444 
{LinkedIn}   
\end{center}
\vspace{-10pt}

\section{\textbf{Professional experience}}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Company 1}{United States}
      {Senior Software Developer}{12/2022 - 12/2023}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \item {item 1},
      \resumeItemListEnd

    

    \resumeSubheading
      {Company4}{Germany}
      {Full Stack Developer}{07/2020 - 07/2021}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \item item1
      \resumeItemListEnd
      
  

    \resumeSubheading{Company6}{Netherlands}{Front-end Developer (part-time)}{Sep 2015 - Sep 2017}
    \resumeItemListStart
        \item {item1}
    \resumeItemListEnd
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

\section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheadingEdu{University of Florida}{USA, FL}{M.Sc. Computer Engineering}{}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

\end{document}
```